# Proofing with Pumping Lemma

Tags: finite-automata, pumping-lemma

Considering a DFA that has an alphabet of {A,B}, and where number of characters A > number of characters B. I don't think such a DFA is possible. Can I proof the impossibility with a Pumping Lemma?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Pumping Lemma here. Have you tried it? If you think that such DFA is not possible it means that the language is not regular - and using the Pumping Lemma you can show if it is the case.

Comment: I tried but I'm not sure how to use Pumping Lemma on an operator like >

Comment: If it were |A| = |B| + 1, would it be easier?